# Neo4j Minimum Spanning Tree not working properly

Tags: neo4j

I have 5 nodes link to each other with bi-direction. I'm trying to find minimum cost to traverse all the nodes. But the result seems quite confusing:

Please refer to below [Nodes linkage][1] diagram.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzCbH.png

After running minimum spanning tree algorithm

```
MATCH (n:Test {eqpId: 'EqpId001'})
CALL gds.alpha.spanningTree.minimum.write({
  nodeProjection: 'Test',
  relationshipProjection: {
                    LINK: {
                            type: 'LINK',
                            properties: 'cost',
                            orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'
                          }
                  },
  startNodeId: id(n),
  relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost',
  writeProperty: 'MINST',
  weightWriteProperty: 'writeCost'
})
YIELD createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount
RETURN createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount;
```

Below is the result:
[Minimum spanning tree result][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBLq7.png

```
"EqpId001"  "EqpId003"  30.0
"EqpId003"  "EqpId002"  25.0
"EqpId001"  "EqpId004"  30.0
"EqpId004"  "EqpId005"  32.0
```

The starting node is EqpId001, how come it jump to EqpId001 out of blue?

Comment: The starting node is EqpId001, how come it jump to EqpId001 out of blue?

What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. My question is: The path is EqpId001->EqpId003->EqpId002 EqpId001->EqpId004->EqpId005 , why there is no route from EqpId002 to EqpId001 ? And why EqpId001 showed up twice?

Comment: There is no path between 01 and 02 because that is not part of the results... 01 shows up twice because it has two relationshipa.... if you look at the image everything looks nice

Comment: But I want to traverse all the 5 nodes, how can I get the result?

Comment: The result clearly shows 5 nodes and 4 relationships

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I was expecting 1-->3-->2-->4->5 instead of 1-->3-->2 1-->4-->5